# Do global variables still cause NPE if I only have one Activity?

Tags: android

I've read many articles about how bad global variables in the application class or in Singletons are. The biggest issue for me was that it causes a NullPointerException when the app gets killed by the system and the user restarts it. The app restarts with the Activity where the user was before and not with the first Activity of the app. The global variables don't stay in memory forever so starting the last Activity causes a NPE (if you don't check for null manually).

All those examples are using apps with multiple activities though. Does this problem still exist with single activity applications?

I've tried to replicate the NullPointerException in my app but on all my devices the app restarts with the first fragment and therefore the app does not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they do. The reason why it didn't crash my app was that I had no fragment where I accessed the singleton's data without creating it first. I fixed it by replacing the singleton with a room database.